# How should I handle binding page-specific events to reusable DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, dom-events

My application has code that is reused across multiple pages. Let's say I have this:

```
+ page_A.html
  - includes partial_1.html
+ page_B.html
  - includes partial_1.html
```

Now, DOM elements in partial_1.html have JavaScript events associated with it. These can be divided into two categories:

- Events that have to be bound regardless of which page the partial is used (type I)
- Events that have to be bound differently, depending on which page the partial is rendered (type II)

The way I have it organized is this:

- partial_1.html --> for the template
- partial_1.css --> for the CSS
- partial_1.js --> for model/controller and type I bindings

  - partial_1__A --> for type II bindings specific to page A
  - partial_1__B --> for type II bindings specific to page B
  - and so on....

Obviously, this could get tiresome if there are many templates. Luckily, at this stage I only have two so it is not a big deal. **However** I am wondering if:

1. There are better ways of handling this
2. I could leverage some existing framework/library. Would *backbone.js* provide some sort of mechanism for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery to bind the events.

I would also put the different bindings in code on the different pages.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use event bubbling.  Assuming these html files are partials and get loaded inside of an existing element you could use jquery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.  This way you would only have an event handler per event and wouldn't have to bind / unbind events as new content was loaded.